# Web - Redirect website url that is being used by a request

Tags: web, request, redirect

> I know that the title isn't very clear, but my problem is kind of complicated.

Lets say I am on this website (lets say, example.com), and the website is taking images from another website ( images.com ).
I want to change something so that instead of images.com, example.com takes images from myimages.com.

Still too complicated? I will break it down more. This is what currently is hapenning:

```
example.com takes images from images.com (I dont know what request it uses)
```

This is want I want:

```
example.com takes images from myimages.com
```

If you still dont understand, please comment below!

Comment: I kind of get it, but why do you want to do this?

Comment: Do you control either web server?

Comment: I control myimages.com, but not example.com

Answer (score 0):

If example.com is database driven, simply download the database and do a find for "images.com" and replace with "myimages.com", then reupload the database.

If it is static HTML, repeat by downloading the HTML from example.com, using something like [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org) to find in files, then replace all in exactly the same way.

As a sidenote, you should provide as much information as possible as to which platform, codebase and type of request you mean. It will generate higher quality answers.

Comment: how do I download a database?

Comment: If you don't know then you probably should tread very carefully to avoid killing your site - but the usual way to do this is to open it in PHPMyAdmin on your hosting provider's control panel and exporting it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time this is done through a GET rest call if done on the server side see https://www.tutorialspoint.com/restful/.

If it is done client side(html css javascript) code you will need to find where that reference is defined in the code and change it. In HTML image tags have an src attribute that tells the page where to grab the image from.

If you go to the example shown here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp 
and change the image tag src like I do below attribute and click run it will show a the stack overflow image located at https://i.stack.imgur.com/oURrw.png.

```
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/oURrw.png" alt="Smiley face" 
 height="42">
```

Comment: example.com is an online game so I think its server sided